# Check if user has certain permissions in Django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-views

I have the following class, named **custom_class.py**. All i need is a way to check in my views **if a certain user is admin**, and **show some DIVs** and if not, hide them. Any help appreciated.

```
class Backend_user:
    parents = {'Administrator': 'None',
               'Supervisor': 'Administrator',
               'Operator': 'Supervisor',
               }
    childs = {'Administrator': 'Supervisor',
              'Supervisor': 'Operator',
              'Operator': 'Boss',
              }

    def __init__(self, user):
        self.user = user
        self.permissions = OrderedDict()
        self.permissions_plural = OrderedDict()
        self.permissions_plural['Administrator'] = 'Administrators'
        self.permissions_plural['Supervisor'] = 'Supervisors'
        if hasattr(user, "administrator"):
            self.my_specialty = getattr(user, 'administrator')
            self.permissions['Administrator'] = True
            self.permissions['Supervisor'] = True
            self.permissions['Operator'] = True
            self.permissions['Boss'] = True
        elif hasattr(user, "supervisor"):
            self.my_specialty = getattr(user, 'supervisor')
            self.permissions['Administrator'] = False
            self.permissions['Supervisor'] = True
            self.permissions['Operator'] = True
            self.permissions['Boss'] = True
```

Comment: are you using django's default user table

Comment: @ArpitSolanki no, i am using custom ones

Comment: what is user in `def __init__(self, user):` ? if this is your base user would you mind posting it as well.

Comment: @ArpitSolanki it's a project i have to "fix" and it's kinda huge. I mean, hundreds of thousands lines of code. All i know is that this class is actually the user permissions schema :/

Comment: so this line `hasattr(user, "administrator")` is checking your user is admin or not?

Comment: @ArpitSolanki yep! I need the same check in views! :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a user table with some name which is also a ForeignKey of Backend_user table so you can simply check if user is admin or not. You have to get the user object from your user table then check if it has the attribute or not

```
def some_view(request):
    user_obj = CustomUser.objects.get(id=some_id) # get the user here
    if hasattr(user_obj, "administrator"):  # checking if user is admin
        # show some div
    else:
        # don't show
```